# How to get data from render in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get `nickname` and `room` from the code below in my frontend JS file. 
Nickname and room are taken from form(POST method). Is there any possibility to get it in simple way?

server:

```js
exports.chatroom = (req, res) => {
    res.render('chatroom', {
        nickname: req.body.nickname,
        room: req.body.room
    });
};
```

client:

```
console.log('here my room and nickname');
```

Comment: Can you be more clear from your code ?

Comment: what exactly you need?

Comment: In you client you are not using any data from your server, you are logging just a string and could you be more clear on what simpler means ?

Comment: Yes. I need to use this data and I don't know how, that's the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add it in your template, e.g.:

```
<script>
  var nickname = "<%nickname%>";
  var room = "<%room%>";
</script>
```

(How it looks like depends on your template engine, the above is EJS which is the default in express)

Comment: Any ideas for PUG?

Comment: Its basically the same.

Comment: I've found it: const nickname = "!{nickname}". Thanks!